# Change dimension of dataframe with repetitive list

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a problem resizing my data frame under R. It is about months and percents. Its size is (29819,2)

```
month   pct
1         1
2       0.9
3       0.8
4       0.7
.
.
.
179    0.25
180     0.1
1         1
2       0.9
3       0.7
.
.
.
179     0.1 
180     0.1
```

I would like my df to look like this : (lots of lines, 180)

```
month    1      2      3      ...      179      180
pct      1    0.9    0.8              0.25      0.1
pct      1    0.9    0.7      ...      0.1      0.1
```

I have tried the reshape method

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "y", timevar = "x" )
```

I have also tried the matrix method, that doesn't seem correct for my problem

```
matrix(unlist(t(df)),byrow=T,180)
```

Can anyone help me finding this please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your dataset in *wide* format by using the `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(month, names_from = month, values_from = pct, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

---

#### Example

```
df <- structure(list(month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 179L, 180L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 179L, 180L), pct = c(1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.25, 0.1, 1, 0.9, 
0.7, 0.1, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(month, names_from = month, values_from = pct, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 2 x 6
#     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4` `179` `180`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   0.9   0.8   0.7  0.25   0.1
# 2     1   0.9   0.7   0.7  0.1    0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

without external libraries

```
df <- data.frame(month = rep(1:180, 2), pct = runif(180*2))
mat <- matrix(df[,"pct"], nrow=2, byrow=T)
```

works for me. 
If you want to have month as first row and row names then

```
mat <- rbind(1:180, mat)
rownames(mat) <- c("month", rep("pct", 2))
```

which looks like this in my case

```
> print(mat[,1:5])
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
month 1.0000000 2.0000000 3.0000000 4.00000000 5.0000000
pct   0.2458001 0.5481397 0.4923737 0.24772985 0.5815464
pct   0.7865478 0.4633333 0.5788609 0.06511907 0.8563442
```